# How do I get Mac OSX current user's directory in C#?

Tags: c#, macos

Right now I have:

```
s = @"/Users/minisquad1/Pictures/";
```

This works alright in my computer. I would feel safer if I could get to the current user's Pictures folder, because right now it obviously works only in my computer.

I have no idea how to do it, ideas anyone?, i'm looking for something like:

```
s = @"/Users/%currentuser%/Pictures/";
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Don't assume that the home directory is located in /Users. You want the equivalent of NSHomeDirectory().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into using the [`Environment.SpecialFolder` enum](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.Environment%2bSpecialFolder). `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` should get you the current user's home directory. There is also a `MyPictures` value that may save you some typing.

```
string s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
```